# Regex to match e-mail in string

Tags: c#, regex

I always get a headache when i try to figure out regex.

I have the following string examples:

> 3;#i_0_.f_membership_john.smith@domain.com_LThumb.jpg
>
> 2;#i_0_.f_membership_jane.doe@domain.com_LThumb.jpg

I need to get the `john.smith@domain.com` piece from the string.  The end of the string will always be `_LThumb.xxx` and the prefix *should* be always `xxx_membership_`.

If someone can come up with some C# regex to help me with this i would be very grateful

Comment: Why use regex? Substring should work out.

Comment: do you want to handle the case where someone has email address alan_LThumb@gmail.com ?

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow does not allow tags in titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\w+?_membership_(\S*?)_LThumb.jpg`

```
\w            # Capture a word character
 +            # One or more times
 ?            # Lazily (smallest match possible)
_membership_  # Literal string
(             # Start capturing group
\S            # Any character that isn't whitespace
 *            # Zero or more times
 ?            # Lazily (smallest match possible)
)             # End capturing group
_LThumb.jpg   # Literal string
```

That includes the "should be there" prefix of `membership` at the front to make sure we pull only what we need out of our string.

The e-mail will be in group 1 of the match.

[You can play with the regex at Regexr](http://regexr.com?31c9d).

Comment: Thank you :)  are you able to break down the regex so i can understand it abit?

Comment: The `[\w\.@]*` may need to be tweaked.  I would suggest something like this: `\S*?`  This does two things:  One, It will allow all valid email address characters to match, and Two, it is not a greedy match, so we get better back-tracking behavior (`\w` matches underscores in some flavors).

Comment: @JohnGietzen Thank you, I tweaked the regex slightly. It should catch more characters for the email now.

Answer (score 3):

Regex should be fine in this situation: use `"_membership_"` and `"_LThumb.jpg"` as your anchors, like this

```
@"_membership_(.*?)_LThumb.jpg"
```

and get the first capturing group which gets everything between the anchors.

```
var email = Regex.Match(
    "2;#i_0_.f_membership_jane.doe@domain.com_LThumb.jpg"
,   @"_membership_(.*?)_LThumb.jpg"
).Groups[1].ToString();
```

This prints

```
jane.doe@domain.com
```

Comment: Both of the above work...Why is one seemingly more complex than the other?  is the "complex" one better for any reason?

Comment: @user257503 The "more complex" version is more restrictive: it makes sure that e-mail is composed of letters, digits, dots, and at signs '@`.

Comment: @user257503 Not necessarily. dasblinkenlight uses `.`, which will match any character, where as I only include letters, periods and @s. He also doesn't bother with the prefix on `_membership`, which is pretty much useless but does help us narrow results down if you have a lot of strings that have similar but not identical patterns.

Comment: @user257503 : dasblinkenlight's version is more permissive. `.*?` would match anything up to the `LThumb.jpg`. So give the string `"3;fl@_membership_#Q*(#Éb╧½_LThumb.jpg"` it would return `#Q*(#Éb╧½`. If you know such garbage will never be in the input you may still be ok with the simpler pattern

Comment: Well, dasblinkenlight's version will allow email addresses like "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" to pass through just fine.  Don't confuse searching with validating.